# How do you limit the overall height of a ListField?

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, listfield

I'm trying to limit the height of a ListField, so that instead of moving down the screen when you move through the items, you only move down inside the box. So, for example, the header on the screen wouldn't disappear.

My current solution doesn't work. The height doesn't change. It stills stays at whatever size the list of objects is. The code I'm using is:

```java
_listField = new ListField()
    {
        protected void layout(int w, int h)
        {
            super.layout(w, 100);
        }
    };
```

Comment: You need to include the BBOS version and device model where you are seeing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this way. In your MainScreen constructor add

```
super(NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL);
```

so your mainscreen will not scroll.

create new manager which has vertical scrolling enabled so only manager will be scrollable like

```
VerticalFieldManager listManager = new VerticalFieldManager(VERTICAL_SCROLL | VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR);
```

Now add your components to this manager say your ListField like

```
listManager.add(your listfield object);
```

If you want to limit the height of listField, then you can set the limit to listManger and add the listfield to manager. so list will be layout in given height of manger like this

```
VerticalFieldManager listManager = new VerticalFieldManager(VERTICAL_SCROLL | VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR); 
{
    protected void sublayout( int maxWidth, int maxHeight )
    {
         int width = Display.getWidth();
         int height = 100;
         super.sublayout( width, height);
         setExtent( width, height);
    }
};
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at putting the list field inside a [MainScreen](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/container/MainScreen.html).  Then you can set the header as the title of the MainScreen.

Comment: It is in a MainScreen. The header is an image though, and I don't want to use a title.

Comment: "I don't want to use a title" isn't a very compelling reason to reject a workable solution.

Comment: It's not a workable solution to my problem? I appreciate the answer, but it's not the solution to my problem. I need a fixed height on a ListField rather than a redesign of the interface.

Comment: Oh, I can feel the appreciation.